# Generic method to fetch data from different core data entities and cast result to respective classes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, casting, nsmanagedobject

I am writing a generic method to fetch data from core data entity with given `entityName`, `predicate` and `sortDescriptors`. I want to return the result as an array of requested entity. If I give Student as `entityName`, I need to return an array of Students as given below,

```
do {
        if let results = try CoreDataController.sharedInstance.masterManagedObjectContext.fetch(request) as? [Student] {

            if results.count > 0 {

                return results
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem here is, how to cast the results to array of respective entity class, in generic method using given entity name?

I have tried to generate class from entity name,

```
let coreDataClass = NSClassFromString(entityName) as! NSManagedObject.Type
```

But it is no taken in array declaration (in the place Student in above code). Please help me to find the correct way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using Swift3.0 ?

Comment: @Wolverine Yes. I am using swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0

Answer (score 7):

You can use Swift Generics for the exact same scenario.

Consider the following Swift (Version 3.0.1) code for fetching an array of object with predicate & sort descriptor provided as parameter (You can define this function in your coredata helper class as a class method):

```
class func arrayOf<T: NSManagedObject>(_ entity: T.Type, 
                                       predicate: NSPredicate? = nil,
                                       sortDescriptor: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil,
                                       context: NSManagedObjectContext = CoreDataHelper.shared.context()) -> NSMutableArray? {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: NSStringFromClass(T.self))

    if predicate != nil {
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate!
    }

    if sortDescriptor != nil {
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptor!
    }

    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {

        let searchResult = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if searchResult.count > 0 {
            // returns mutable copy of result array
            return NSMutableArray.init(array: searchResult)
        } else {
            // returns nil in case no object found
            return nil
        }

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.